# MySql: are nested tables possible?

Tags: mysql

How can I design a table to hold the following data:

```
name
age
last_30_measurements
    timestamp, value
    timestamp, value
    timestamp, value
    timestamp, value
    ..
```

As you can see, `last_30_measurements` could be its own table, containing a list of pairs timestamp,value.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: indeed it could be its own table, and it _should_ be. That's the correct way to do it. Study the topics of database normalisation, entity relationships and foreign keys (all aspects of the same thing, essentially) to know how to design a relational database correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use another table for that purpose and use a foreign keys to link both.

In example :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE mesurer_dude
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE mesurements
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    mesure_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    mesure_value INT NOT NULL,
    mesurer_dude_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (mesurer_dude_id) REFERENCES mesurer_dude(id)
);

INSERT INTO mesurer_dude VALUES (default, "John", 42), (default, "Jane", 69);
INSERT INTO mesurements VALUES (default, NOW(), 10, 1), (default, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 20, 1), (default, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), 25, 1), (default, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), 15, 1), (default, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY), 12, 2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
-- get the last 30 mesurements of john
SELECT *
FROM mesurer_dude d
INNER JOIN mesurements m
ON d.id=m.mesurer_dude_id
WHERE d.name = 'John'
ORDER BY m.mesure_date DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Result :

```
| id  | name | age | id  | mesure_date         | mesure_value | mesurer_dude_id |
| --- | ---- | --- | --- | ------------------- | ------------ | --------------- |
| 1   | John | 42  | 4   | 2018-11-25 14:37:33 | 15           | 1               |
| 1   | John | 42  | 3   | 2018-11-24 14:37:33 | 25           | 1               |
| 1   | John | 42  | 2   | 2018-11-23 14:37:33 | 20           | 1               |
| 1   | John | 42  | 1   | 2018-11-22 14:37:33 | 10           | 1               |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Excellent example Cid, thanks! Now let me study this and hopefully implement it.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY` and `JOIN` are the keywords you can focus your searches on (in fact, they work together)